# Star Trek: The Next Generation episode with a black snowman

Tags: story-identification, star-trek, star-trek-tng, episode-identification

My three-year-old daughter has just been telling me about an episode of The Next Generation which was on earlier.

> The man runned on the sand and he fell in the black thing, and he came up a black snowman.

Followed by

> The mans had their orange torches, and they threw fire on the black snowman and it melted.

My curiosity is piqued; can anyone help me identify this episode where phaser fire (I presume) melts a black creature in a sandy environment?

Comment: Starting 'em on TNG early, eh?  Good parenting, there.  :-)

Comment: If only more ST:TNG episodes could be synopsized that way.

Comment: Can this be a regular feature of the site? We get small children to watch and describe Star Trek or other sci fi shows, then we have to work out the episode?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

[image: black snowman]

My best guess is ["Skin of Evil"](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Skin_of_Evil_(episode)) (S01E23), in which Riker gets absorbed by what could be described compactly as [a sludge monster](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Armus) and is later spat out covered in [Metamucil and printer ink](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Skin_of_Evil_(episode)#Props_and_effects).  While the monster isn't destroyed, melted, or even harmed by phaser fire, I'm quite certain that at some point he responds to phaser fire by "melting down" into a less anthropomorphic, more ooze-like form and retreating.

Comment: Wife has confirmed this is indeed the one. Thanks!

Comment: Ah yes, Tar vs. Yar.

Comment: @GrahamBorland Y'all must have some creepy-looking snowmen where you're at.

Comment: I'd be more concerned with the kind of snow creatures your child has been exposed to.

Comment: Hey, that "sludge monster" has a name.  It's "Armus", apparently.  I've always admired Armus for not being complicated or misunderstood like all the other aliens on _Star Trek_: He's pretty much just a slimewad, physically _and_ spiritually.

Comment: @DougWarren He might be called Armus but he's certainly not harmless.

Comment: Doug Warren - and Armus was named after Burton Armus, a producer on TNG at that time.  I'm not sure he felt flattered by that "honor"..